# an attempt was made to request new permissions for a session that has a pending request

Tags: android, facebook, permissions

hi i'm developing android app with facebook SDK 3.0 new.

i tried to request 'publish_stream' permission after user login.
so, in onSessionStateChange(), i put my code which request 'publsh_stream' permission, but it doesn't work.

here is my code:

```
private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

    if (state.isOpened()) {

        if (pendingPublishReauthorization &&   state.equals(SessionState.OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED)) {
            pendingPublishReauthorization = false;
            publishFeed(userName);
        }

        m_pd.show();
        Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                if (user != null) {

                    String username=buildUserInfoDisplay(user);
                    userName=username;
                    saveAccount(username, "facebook");

                    Log.d(com.dress.folio.Constants.FACEBOOK_TAG, "login success");
                    //publishFeed(userName);
                    m_pd.dismiss();

                    h.postDelayed(irun, 1000);
                    Activity GetActivity=getActivity();
                    if(GetActivity != null) GetActivity.finish();

                }
            }
        });


        List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
        if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions) ) {

            pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
            //if(state == SessionState.OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED) {
                Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);
                session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
            //}

        }



    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        Log.i(com.dress.folio.Constants.FACEBOOK_TAG, "Logged out..." + exception);
    }
}
```

at the line session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);, compiler always say error like: an attempt was made to request new permissions for a session that has a pending request.

how can i request publish_stream right after user facekbook SSO login in my app.??

Answer (score 11):

I just facing the same issue, the on onActivityResult method was overrided .
So make sure calling  :

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
```

This method should call your callback after.
More info here (Section 6):  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/

Comment: In my activity the method "super.onActivityResult(...)" wasn't called. so follow your code, and make sure where using facebook "Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult" has been called. this error you get, mean like you try to login somewhere but you never consume the anwser.

Comment: I almost ignored this because of the low votes, not accepted answer and bad comments, but this is **correct**! Thanks!

Comment: **this** is the answer.

Comment: This is the correct answer. 
If you are using fragments, put that in your parent activity.